# Information hints in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a dialog in which setting are displayed. Also there is an help button on right top of the dialog.

[image]

After pressing this button and selecting any control on the dialog no help hints were shown.
How can I add these hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably [`QWidget::setWhatsThis`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#whatsThis-prop). You use this with the control which you want to explain (i.e. the one which the user clicks on after having clicked the `?` button).

```
emailTextEdit->setWhatsThis(tr("The receipt will be sent to this e-mail address."));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [QWhatsThis](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwhatsthis.html).

As stated in the documentation, the QWhatsThis class *"provides a simple description of any widget, i.e. answering the question "What's This?"."*

In essence "What's This?" is a mode a user can enter into, in which What's This information is displayed about the widget/its action which has the focus. This mode can be entered into by pressing shift+F1 or via the question mark icon you have illustrated in your question. A call to `QWhatsThis::enterWhatsThisMode()` will have the same result.

To set things up you can use a QWidget's [setWhatsThis(const QString &)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#whatsThis-prop), a QAction's [setWhatsThis(const QString & what)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#whatsThis-prop), or even use QWhatsThis's [createAction(QObject * parent)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwhatsthis.html#createAction) to set up the action for you.